# Monorepo on top of many small git repos

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to get a monorepo-like experience on top of several small git repos.

`git submodules` is not a solution. Maybe it is a way my prefered way is implemented, but submodules alone don't solve the problem.

For example I have monorepo which contains 3 git repos.

Required Features:

- Imagine I change five files, which are in three different git repos. I want to commit all changes with a single command. For example this changed git repos `repo-a`, `repo-b` and `repo-c`
- If I look at a commit in `repo-a` I want an easy way to see the related changes in the repos `repo-b` and `repo-c`
- I want to be able to create a branch with a single command. This should automatically create branches in all repos in the monorepo.
- A command line interface is needed. GUI is not needed.
- open source with a non-GPL license.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it yet, but [repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/README.md) is an open source tool which helps to manage several git repos.

> Repo is a tool built on top of Git. Repo helps manage many Git repositories, does the uploads to revision control systems, and automates parts of the development workflow. Repo is not meant to replace Git, only to make it easier to work with Git.

Answer (score 0):

The [gerrit-review](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/) documentation lists two ways to do multi-project management.

One is "sub-modules", the other is via a tool called "repo"